# I cant stop my interval and neither clearInterval() work;

Tags: javascript

I've made simple userscript for the game https://zty.pe/, The bot work on my modified version of the game, I'm trying to make it whenever I click "F" it starts running , but stops when I click " C ", the loop works normally after clicking C and it doesnt stop.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  key = e.keyCode
  if(key == 70){
  var zTypeBotAlphaChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var zTypeBotCharToType = 0;
  ztypebot = setInterval(function() {
  ig.game.shoot(
  zTypeBotAlphaChars.charAt(zTypeBotCharToType));
  }
  , 10);
  }
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 67){
    clearInterval(ztypebot, 10);
  }
})
```

Comment: two things you could try are making `ztypebot` something like a `window.ztypebot` and/or adding the `c` keydown inside the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `window.` before `ztypebot` interval to make it a global function:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  key = e.keyCode
  if(key == 70){
  var zTypeBotAlphaChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var zTypeBotCharToType = 0;
  window.ztypebot = setInterval(function() {
  ig.game.shoot(
  zTypeBotAlphaChars.charAt(zTypeBotCharToType));
  }
  , 10);
  }
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 67){
    clearInterval(window.ztypebot, 10);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ztypebot` variable is local in each function, you need to define it outside like so:

```
let ztypebot;

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  ...
  ztypebot = setInterval(function() {
    ...
  }
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 67){
    clearInterval(ztypebot, 10);
  }
})
```